# Compute bill for a gem store

Tags: python, logic

Below is my code to compute the bill for the gem store. **I'm able to get correct prices for the right elements from the list but I'm not able to figure out how to multiply them with the required quantity (reqd_qty list) and calculate the total price.**

Following is the complete problem description.

Tanishq Gems Store sells different varieties of gems to its customers.

Write a Python program to calculate the bill amount to be paid by a customer based on the list of gems and quantity purchased. If any gem required by the customer is not available in the store, then consider the total bill amount to be -1.

Assume that quantity required by the customer for any gem will always be greater than 0

```
def calculate_bill_amount(gems_list, price_list, reqd_gems,reqd_quantity):
bill_amount=0
#Write your logic here
for gem in gems_list:
    for g in reqd_gems:
        if g==gem:
            index = gems_list.index(g)
            price = price_list[index]
            print(price) 


return bill_amount

#List of gems available in the store
gems_list=["Emerald","Ivory","Jasper","Ruby","Garnet"]

#Price of gems available in the store. gems_list and price_list have one-to- 
one correspondence
price_list=[1760,2119,1599,3920,3999]

#List of gems required by the customer
reqd_gems=["Ivory","Emerald","Garnet"]

#Quantity of gems required by the customer. reqd_gems and reqd_quantity have 
one-to-one correspondence
reqd_quantity=[3,2,5]

bill_amount=calculate_bill_amount(gems_list, price_list, reqd_gems, 
reqd_quantity)
print(bill_amount)
```

**Current Output:**

```
1760 # Ivory Price
2119 # Emerald Price
3999 # Garnet Price
0 # Bill amount
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you read up on dictionaries, looping over lists to match a value in another list is very inefficient. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

```
gems_list = ["Emerald", "Ivory", "Jasper", "Ruby", "Garnet"]
price_list = [1760, 2119, 1599, 3920, 3999]
reqd_gems = ["Ivory", "Emerald", "Garnet"]
reqd_quantity = [3, 2, 5]

quantity_dict = dict(zip(reqd_gems, reqd_quantity))
price_dict = dict(zip(gems_list, price_list))
print("Item", "Quantity", "Unit_price", "Total_price")
for k, v in quantity_dict.items():
    print(k, v, price_dict[k], price_dict[k] * v)
print("Grand_total", sum([price_dict[k] * v for k, v in quantity_dict.items()]))
```

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed out in an answer to you before you deleted this same question earlier: `bill_amount` should just be the sum of all of the prices you calculate along the way, so after your print(price) command, try adding `bill_amount += price`. This sets the value of `bill_amount` to its current value plus the new value of `price`.  Though you're still not multiplying this price by its quantity.

Also, your code doesn't address the case of a gem not being in the availability list.  So one way around this is to skip the calculation and return -1 if `g` is not in `gems_list`.  You can use the command "`if g not in gems_list:`".

```
def calculate_bill_amount2(gems_list, price_list, reqd_gems,reqd_quantity):
    bill_amount=0
    #Write your logic here
    for gem in gems_list:
        for g in reqd_gems:
            if g==gem:
                index = gems_list.index(g)
                no_of_gems = reqd_quantity[reqd_gems.index(g)]
                price = price_list[index] * no_of_gems
                print(price)
                bill_amount += price
            if g not in gems_list:
                return -1                
    return bill_amount
```

Frankly, I'd just use dictionaries instead of lists, because you're doing a lot of unnecessary looping:

```
def calculate_bill_amount(gem_prices, reqd_gem_quantities):
    bill_amount = 0
    for gem in reqd_gem_quantities: 
        if gem in gem_prices:
            price = gem_prices[gem] * reqd_gem_quantities[gem]
            bill_amount += price
        else:
            return -1
    return bill_amount

gem_prices = { "Emerald": 1760, "Ivory": 2119, "Jasper": 1599, "Ruby": 3920, "Garnet": 3999 }
reqd_gem_quantities = { "Ivory": 3, "Emerald": 2, "Garnet": 5 }

print(calculate_bill_amount(gem_prices, reqd_gem_quantities))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two main flaws with the logic of your program. 
The first being is that you never update *bill_amount*, that is why your answer is being returned a 0.
Secondly, the price is not being multiplied by the required quantity.
Here is calculate_bill_amount() reworked:

```
def calculate_bill_amount(gems_list, price_list, reqd_gems,reqd_quantity):
bill_amount=0
#Write your logic here
x=0 
for g in reqd_gems:
    for gem in gems_list:
        if g==gem:
            index = gems_list.index(g)
            price = price_list[index]
            bill_amount += price * reqd_quantity[x] 
            print(bill_amount, price, reqd_quantity[x], x)
    x+=1
return(bill_amount)
```

@Bill .M was also right in pointing out that you didn't account for the condition where the gem was not in the list

Answer (score 0):

```
def calculate_bill_amount(gems_list, price_list, reqd_gems,reqd_quantity):
    bill_amount=0
    #Write your logic here
    j=0
    for i in reqd_gems:
        if i in gems_list:
            index=gems_list.index(i)
            bill_amount=bill_amount+reqd_quantity[j]*price_list[index]
            j=j+1
        else:
            bill_amount=-1
            break
    if(bill_amount>30000):
        bill_amount=bill_amount-(bill_amount*5/100)

    return bill_amount
```

Comment: It's always useful to give a bit of explanation about what you've changed and/or how your answer is different/better than the other answers

Answer (score 0):

```
def calculate_bill_amount(gems_list, price_list, reqd_gems,reqd_quantity):
bill_amount=0
dict1={}
dict2={}
k=0
for i in reqd_gems:
    dict2[i]=reqd_quantity[k]
    k+=1
k=0
for i in gems_list:
    dict1[i]=price_list[k]
    k+=1
for i in dict2.keys():
    gem=i
    if gem in dict1.keys():
        bill_amount+=dict1[gem]*dict2[gem]
    else:
        bill_amount=-1
        break
if bill_amount>30000:
    bill_amount=bill_amount-(bill_amount*5/100)
return bill_amount
```

*The above code works fine.. here i created two dictionary and mapped the correspondence..but i'm also new to programming so i don't know whether it is efficient or not *